# replace null to ""test"" in a file using unix

Tags: linux, csv

I have below pattern in my file at different lines

```
""key"": null
```

I want to replaceu this to

```
""key"": ""test""
```

through linux

i used the below commands:

```
sed -i 's/ null / ""test"" /'
sed -i 's/ null / \"\"test\"\" /'
```

but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 sed -i 's/null/\"\"test\"\"/g' file.txt
```

Comment: it is also removing the delimiter from the files, replacing comma to space

Comment: comma in where?

Comment: sorry that was my mistakes i used this wrongly, thanks @Arash